# textArea appear only if you minimize or select the text, how do i fix this?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, interface, jtextarea

Im doing my first graphic interface but i faced this problem, the text area textArea appear only if you minimize or select the text.
I tried many things but nothing worked, can somebody help?

here is the code:

```
package lln_urn;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class Urn {
    //ATTRIBUTES

    //main frame
    private final JFrame frame;

    //various components
    private final JTextArea explanation_textarea;
    
    //font
    private final Font font = new Font("Segoe", Font.BOLD, 20);


    //CONSTRUCT
    public Urn() {
    
        //setup of the window
        frame = new JFrame("Law of large numbers");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 320);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    
        //textarea
        explanation_textarea = new JTextArea();
        explanation_textarea.setBounds(5,0,300,50);
        explanation_textarea.setText("In this urn there are 2000 balls");
        explanation_textarea.setEditable(false);
            
        //adding components
        frame.add(explanation_textarea);
    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Urn urn = new Urn();
    }

}
```

[the output that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1fbC.png)
[how it looks after i minimize and take it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxten.png)

I tried:
setting bounds to different size,
setting to editable,
change the layout,
change the background and text color,
add the textarea to a panel,
update the jdk,

Nothing solved the problem, i have no idea what else to try.

Comment: Set `setVisible` of the frame AFTER you've added ALL the components to the UI

Comment: hard-coded sizing/locating of components is __wrong__, always - instead learn how to use layoutManagers, see f.i. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. leave default JFrame layout (BOrderLayout)
2. do not set textarea bounds - layout manages the objects inside
3. call frame.setVisible as last